# NDSolve::ivhead

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear

*trying to solve system of nonlinear pdes, which method is best?*
*initial and boundary on all the two variables keeping just as zero, such 
     that no incompatibility issue occurs, for test*

*but an error occurs, how can I deal with that?*

```
 \[Epsilon] = 0.0168; Subscript[\[Tau], 0] =0.02; \[Beta] = 1.0; a = 1;
   pde = {D[\[Theta][x, t], x, x] - D[\[Theta][x, t], t] - \
  [Epsilon]*D[u[x,t], t, x] - 
  Subscript[\[Tau], 0]*D[\[Theta][x, t], t, t] - 
  Subscript[\[Tau], 0]*\[Epsilon]*
  D[u[x, t], t, t,x] == -\[Beta]*(Subscript[\[Tau], 0]*(D[\[Theta][x, t], 
  x])^2 +
    Subscript[\[Tau], 0]*\[Epsilon]*D[\[Theta][x, t], t]*
    D[u[x, t], x] - D[\[Theta][x, t], x]*D[\[Theta][x, t], x]),  
  D[u[x, t], x, x] - a*D[\[Theta][x, t], x] - 
  D[u[x, t], t,t] == -\[Beta]*(D[\[Theta][x, t], x])*(D[u[x, t], x] - 
   a*\[Theta][x, t])};

 bc = {\[Theta][x, 0] == 0, 
  D[\[Theta][x, 0], t] == 0, \[Theta][0, t] == 0, \[Theta][1, t] == 
   0, D[u[x, 0], x] == 0, D[u[x, 0], x, t] == 0 , u[x, 0] == 0, 
  D[u[x, 0], t] == 0 , u[0, t] == 0, u[1, t] == 0 }

 sol = NDSolve[{pde, bc}, {\[Theta], u}, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 500}, 
  Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
    "MinPoints" -> 10}}}]

 Plot3D[Evaluate[T[x, t] /. sol[[1]]], {t, 0, 5}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: This looks like a difficult problem.  To get started, replace `pde, bc` by `{pde, bc}` in `NDSolve`, and look at the documentation for `ClearAll`.

Comment: Using the "MethodOfLines", as specified in the question, results in the error message, `NDSolve::ivone - NDSolve::ivone: Boundary values may only be specified for one independent variable. Initial values may only be specified at one value of the other independent variable.`  Deleting the `Method` specification in the question cause Mathematica to default to FEM instead, resulting in the error message, `NDSolve::femcmsd - The spatial derivative order of the PDE may not exceed two.`  All this does not mean that Mathematica cannot solve the problem, but a lot of work probably will be required.

Comment: I should add that some  of the boundary conditions are inconsistent.  For instance, is `u[500,1]` equal to `1` or `.2`?

Comment: Some boundary conditions are inconsistent. It was a mistake.Thanks for mentioning it.  How many initial and boundary condition is necessary to solve the above system of pde? How can I set those conditions? I just want to see theta(0,t)=1 and (del u/ del x)= a(=coefficient of del theta/del x in 2nd pde )

Comment: I think you have enough boundary conditions now.  I suggest that you edit your question to make the boundary conditions consistent, make the two corrections I mentioned in my first comment, run your code, and add the error messages you receive to the question.

Comment: changes boundary condition such that it will be consistent as: bc = { theta[0, t] == 1, D[u[0, t], x] == a, 
   theta[x, 0] - KroneckerDelta[x, 0] == 0, D[theta[x, 0], t] == 0, 
   u[x, 0] == 0, D[u[x, 0], t] == 0, theta[xmax, t] == 0, 
   u[xmax, t] == 0}; setting xmax=100, tmax=50

Comment: Please make all necessary changes in the question, not in comments.  Also, I recommend against using `KroneckerDelta[x, 0]` in boundary conditions.  Numerical discretization of PDEs implicitly assumes a smoothly varying solution.

Comment: Did you see the help for `NDSolve::ivone` this will lead you to `ref/message/NDSolve/ivone` that has examples for what causes this type of error.